# Make login form unreaching by pressing back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have a login form and after the user has entered correct user and password info, they will be taken to a welcome form. I don't want the user to go back to the login form from anywhere in the app without logging out first. The only way they can go back to the login form is by pressing back. How can I stop that?

Edit:
The following is the code that performs the login.

```
private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(String... params) {
            User user;
            try {
                user = RestCommunicator.authenticateUser(params[0], params[1]);
            } catch (NetworkException e) {
                user = new User();
                user.setResponseStatus("Network Error");
            }
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User result) {
            if (result != null && result.getUsername() != null
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("Network Error")
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("wrong-user")
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("wrong-password")) {
                Log.d("result", "*" + result.getResponseStatus() + "*");
                userDao.insertOrReplace(result);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("loggedin", true);
                editor.commit();
                super.onPostExecute(result);                
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                        WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                        LoginErrorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("error", result.getResponseStatus());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 90000);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: could you post some code?

Answer (score 4):

Add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to your intent...it will remove the `SplashActivity` from the activity stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

**OR**, you can do the same task by setting `true` to `android:noHistory` in your `Manifest.xml` file when you declare your activity as below...

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" >
```

**Update:**

Update your `AsyncTask` as below by adding a contructor with `Context` as a parameter...

```
   private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {

        private Context mContext;

        public UserLoginTask(Context context) {

            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(String... params) {
            User user;
            try {
                user = RestCommunicator.authenticateUser(params[0], params[1]);
            } catch (NetworkException e) {
                user = new User();
                user.setResponseStatus("Network Error");
            }
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User result) {
            if (result != null && result.getUsername() != null
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("Network Error")
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("wrong-user")
                    && !result.getResponseStatus().equals("wrong-password")) {
                Log.d("result", "*" + result.getResponseStatus() + "*");
                userDao.insertOrReplace(result);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("loggedin", true);
                editor.commit();
                super.onPostExecute(result);    

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WelcomeActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) this.mContext).finish();

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginErrorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("error", result.getResponseStatus());
                mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 90000);

            }

        }
    }
```

Then call your `AsyncTask` in your activity as below...

```
UserLoginTask loginTask = new UserLoginTask(SplashActivity.this);
loginTask.execute();
```

Comment: is both option failed?

Answer (score 1):

**WAY-1**

You can implement this from your AndroidManifest.xml file

By just adding `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in `LoginActivity`.

[Android Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)

**WAY-2**

Remove LoginActivity from stack by setting flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a transparent activity as the launcher activity for your app, let's call it Intro.

Inside the OnResume() method you decide which activity to launch based on the state of the registration.

Remember to set the `android:noHistory="true"` both on your Intro activity and the activity you decide to launch. This way the launched activity is not stored on the activities stack and you by pressing `back` you directly exit from the application.

Your manifest file should be like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Intro"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.example.AuthActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_auth"
        android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.example.WorkingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_working"
        android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```

Your Intro.OnResume:

```
Class toLaunch = null;
//status String is the value stored after registration/authentication
//you can store it using shared preferences
        if(status.equals("invalid"){
            toLaunch = RegistrationActivity.class;
        } else if (status.equals("registered")){
            toLaunch = AuthActivity.class; 
        } else if (status.equals("authOk")){
            toLaunch = WorkingActivity.class;
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bad Status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(Intro.this,toLaunch);
        startActivity(i);
```